# what C++ software do i use for accelerated c++ book

Tags: c++

I have just bought accelerated c++ used. It wants me to do a project but i have no clue on what, does any one have a clue i searched online for a answer but nothing or at less one that would work. The program it want me to do is this

write a program that, when run, writes
 this (") is a qute, and this (/) is a backslash

3 + 4;

Comment: Any C++ compiler and/or IDE of your choice.

Comment: I think you commented in the wrong place.

Comment: thank you @bames53 i will keep that in mind. Its been a long time since i played with coding. And sorry for any misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

There is no particular implementation you're supposed to use. You simply use whatever you've got. If you're on Windows you can get Visual Studio Express. If you're on linux you can use gcc, if you're on OS X you can get Xcode, etc.

*Accelerated C++* is not intended for individuals new to programming; It's intended to get a programmer with experience in another language up and running in C++ quickly. You may find a different book more suited to your needs.

Comment: I agree with your second point. If OP doesn't know what an IDE is, and isn't even at a "hello world" level, they should really be using a much more introductory text.

Comment: You make a good point about the intended skill level of the book, but I don't really understand how this Q/A is useful to the community.

Comment: @tylerdude If you want to learn programming and you want to do so using C++ then _Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++_ is a good option. You can get a sample of its content [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/). The [C++ Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) has a couple other options (as well as _Accelerated C++_, though it mentions the point about being for programmers with previous experience).